# Overloading the [] operator with no array internally

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have seen the following code:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    int mA;
    int mB;
    int mC;
    int mD;

    int operator[] (const int index) const
    {
        return ((int*)(this))[index];
    }
};
```

How does this work? I know the this keyword is a pointer to this class but without property knowing how many variables there are ... how can we safely access [index] of "this" pointer?

Comment: Just by pure chance this works

Comment: it doesn't really work, this is undefined behavior. if your class was more complicated it would definitely give you gibberish

Comment: So even if the user is a good citizen and only use index from 0 to 3 ... it is still not guaranteed that index 0 returns mA ?

Comment: It's not guaranteed by the standard. But your compiler likely provides guarantees about how it's packing behaves, and these can often by manipulated using `#pragma`s. Although you can "make this happen" (or something similar) on most compilers, portability between compilers is difficult/impossible if you go this route.

Comment: if class uses inheritance, then that will affect the layout. if the class has multiple children after these 4, and something about it causes the compiler to change the padding of the structure for beneficial alignment or something, then this won't work. in general, if you want to get member variable from pointer to class, you need to use `pointer to member` syntax, that's why it exists. casting to int * and making assumptions about alignment is undefined behavior. i'm not even sure if standard requires that mA is laid out before mB above, that might be different on other compilers.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon There is no guarantee that the distance between those variables are `sizeof(int)`, which is what an array of int guarantees you.

Comment: @Chris Beck: The compiler is not allowed to re-order members.

Comment: @VoidStar: I see so there can be padding but not reordering?

Comment: @ChrisBeck index `0` absolutely will return `mA`; the spec guarantees that casting a pointer to a standard layout object to the appropriate type will yield a pointer to the first member of the object. So index `0` _is_ guaranteed to work.

Comment: @barnes53: Yeah but it makes things fragile in the sense that if someone adds something to the class that makes it not standard layout, then suddenly your class is broken. Maybe there is some SFINAE trick you can use to `static_assert` that the class is standard layout? But anyways it's clearly adding some complexity / maintenance burden to do things this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of thing is not recommended, because it is not guaranteed by the C++ standard. However, most compilers do explicitly define their memory layout behaviors (often on a per-architecture basis) and provide `#pragma`s for manipulating the packing behavior (such as `#pragma pack` in MSVC). If you understand/leverage these features, you can make it work on most given compilers/architectures. **However, it will *not* be portable!** For each new compiler, you'd need to re-test and adjust, a costly maintenance task. Generally, we prefer greater ease of portability.

If you really want to do this, you can add a `static_assert` to verify the compiler's behavior.

```
int operator[] (const int index) const
{
    static_assert(sizeof(SomeClass) == 4 * sizeof(mA), "Padding not supported");
    return ((int*)(this))[index];
}
```

Because the standard does not allow members to be reordered, logically we can deduce that if the size of `SomeClass` is 16, then this code will work as expected. With the assert, we are at least notified if somebody builds on a different compiler and it tries to pad it (thus messing us up).

However, we can be standards-compliant and achieve names for array slots. You might consider a pattern such as:

```
class SomeClass
{
    enum Index {
        indexA,
        indexB,
        indexC,
        indexD,

        indexCount;
    };

    int mData[indexCount];

public:
    int operator[] (const int index) const
    {
        return mData[index];
    }

    int& A() { return mData[indexA]; }
    int& B() { return mData[indexB]; }
    int& C() { return mData[indexC]; }
    int& D() { return mData[indexD]; }
};
```

This provides similar functionality, but is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: Interesting :) Thanks for this awesome alternative

Comment: A couple of quibbles:   `sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed to be `4`, although it is with a fair proportion of modern compilers.      Also, if a struct contains 4 `int`s and no members of other types, all of them will be aligned, without need for padding.   By default, the padding will (potentially) only come to play for structs that contain members of multiple types, since alignment requirements vary with type. The alignment of the struct will be determined by alignment requirement of its first member, with padding to ensure alignment of all other members.

Comment: @Peter The C++ standard allows padding to be inserted anywhere (except at the start). The compiler could align all the 4-byte ints to 8 byte boundaries if it really wanted.

Comment: There's more to it than that, M.M.   When all members of a struct are of the same type, all members have the same alignment requirement.   And since the alignment requirement for all types allows for elements of an array to be stored contiguously .....

Answer (score 0):

This 'works' only because it's undefined behavior. The memory location the compiler chooses for `mB` happens to be the same as `&mA + 1`, the address for `mC` is `&mA + 2` and `&mB + 1` and so on.

However it is true that the class is 'standard layout' (all data members have same access specifier and no inheritance is being used [n3337 § 9 p7]), which traditionally does produce this organization of the member variables. It's not guaranteed though. 'standard layout' could mean something else, such as some amount of padding between the members [n3337 § 9.2 p14], but I doubt there's any platform which actually does that.

The spec does say that it's legal to get the address one past an object, so calculating `&mA + 1` is legal. [n3337 § 5.7 p5] And the spec does also say that a pointer with the correct type and value does point at an object regardless of how the pointer is calculated.

> If an object of type T is located at an address A, a pointer of type cv T* whose value is the address A is said to point to that object, regardless of how the value was obtained. [Note: For instance, the address one past the end of an array (5.7) would be considered to point to an unrelated object of the array’s element type that might be located at that address. *— [n3337 § 3.9.2 p3]*

After reviewing §5.9 and §5.10 I think the following may be technically legal, though it could possibly have unspecified behavior:

```
if (&mA + 1 == &mB && &mB + 1 == &mC && &mC + 1 == &mD) {
    return ((int*)(this))[index];
}
```

Even the cast is legal, since the spec says a standard layout class can be cast to a pointer to its first member. [n3337 § 9.2 p20]